# Ignore lines with quotes or get DataWeave will to read invalid CSV

Tags: csv, mule, dataweave

I'm trying to use Mule's DataWeave component to read a CSV file that isn't valid, or at least doesn't conform to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180). The issue is that there are some values that contain quotes, but the field isn't escaped. For example,

```
col1,col2,col3
one,two "two" two,three
one",two,three
```

Is there a way to straightforward way to slightly relax the rules in the CSV parser that DataWeave uses so that it will treat a value that does not start with a double-quote as a non-escaped value? Alternatively, can I (either using DataWeave or some other transformation) ignore all lines of text that have a quote in them? It's less than a fraction of one percent of the rows, and those rows by chance aren't relevant for this integration anyway, but I can't control the CSV generation.

**edit:** Here's an example:

*CSV*

```
Column A,Column B,Column C,Column D
A,Something Weird",C,D
A,B,Something Else" Weird,D,
A,",S,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g, ,N,o,r,m,a,l,",C,D
```

*DataWeave*

```
%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/json
---
payload
```

*Output*

```
[
  {
    "Column A": "A",
    "Column B": ",C,D\r\nA,B,Something Else",
    "Column C": "D",
    "Column D": ""
  },
  {
    "Column A": "A",
    "Column B": ",S,o,m,e,t,h,i,n,g, ,N,o,r,m,a,l,",
    "Column C": "C",
    "Column D": "D"
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

> Alternatively, can I (either using DataWeave or some other transformation) ignore all lines of text that have a quote in them?

Sure. Just remove all lines containing a double-quote from the input, *before* your DataWeave transformer.

Comment: How can I do that? It's not obvious to me how to remove lines from an InputStream. What transformer would I use? As in, do I have to do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076873, or is there some built-in transformer?